# Android Build Tools installed at '/Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools'

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, appium, robotframework

I a m trying to run Android automation in Robot Framework using Appium but, the following error keeps showing up:

> WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools/adb","/Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools/emulator/adb","/Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools/tools/adb","/Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools'?

I have checked the installation in Android as well.
[image]

Any idea how to resolve this kind of issue? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens when you run `adb` by itself in your terminal? How about `which adb`?

Comment: You have to add also **build-tools** path in **path** variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your paths may not be set correctly. For reference, I have the following set in my [bash profile](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```